# Remove page id from url with mod_rewrite

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I want to go from `www.site.com/page.php?url=string.html` to `www.site.com/string.html`

My .htaccess looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+).html$ page.php?url=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+).html/$ page.php?url=$1
```

But it does not do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following rewrites:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /cms/page\.php\?url=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^page\.php$ /%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^.*\.html$ /cms/page.php?url=$0 [QSA,L]
```

### EDIT

Since the page is inside `/cms` directory, updated the rules to reflect the same.

Comment: Stil don't do anything. Could it be because I test it on a subdomain? - The testing domain is: subdomain.site.com/cms/page.php?url=string.html

Comment: You sir! You have saved my day, thank you very much.